# Centralizar horizontalmente a logo da página html css

Tags: html, layout, css

Como centralizar horizontalmente meu logo, essa minha seta não está muito centralizada horizontalmente, queria que estivesse... Alguém pode me ajudar? Tentei o top: 50% e não funcionou...

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.postagem {
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,.05);
 margin: 0px;
}
#interface {
 width: 1200px;
 background-color: white;
 margin: 90px auto 10px auto;
 box-shadow: 0px 4px 6px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.cabecalho {
 transition: 0.2s;
 top: 0px;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 38px;
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,1);
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
} 
.logo {
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 font-family: agency fb;
 font-size: 20pt;
 /*display: inline-block;*/
}
#fcor {
 color: rgba(255,220,180,1);
}
.artigo {
 padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
}

.titulo {
 font-family: arial;
 font-size: 12pt;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
 margin: 0px 0px 5px 0px; 
 padding: 0px;
}

.paragrafo {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
 font-family: arial;
 text-align: justify;
}
.li {
 font-size: 20pt;
 font-weight: 900;
}
.link {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.link:hover {
 font-style: none;
 text-decoration: underline;
}
.icone {
 transition: 2s;
 border: solid white 6px;
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 height: 300px;
 width: 300px;
}
#flecha {
 left: 10px;
 position: absolute; 
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
/*Folhas de estilo de tabela*/
.tabela {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tdn {
 border: solid black 2px;
 padding: 2px;
}
.vazio {
 border: solid black 2px;
 padding: 12px;
}
.vazio#vm {
 padding: 36px;
}
.tabt {
 background-color: white;
 padding: 2px;
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.subt {
 background-color: lightgray;
 padding: 2px;
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.ft {
 border: solid black 2px;
}
.asst {
 padding: 12px;
 font-weight: 900;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_css/estilo.css"/>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).scroll(function() {
 var y = $(this).scrollTop();
 if (y < 25) {
  $('.cabecalho').css({'padding-top': '20px','padding-bottom': '20px'});
 } else {
  $('.cabecalho').css({'padding-top': '6px', 'padding-bottom': '3px'});
 }
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body class="postagem">
  <header class="cabecalho">
   <a href="1009182.html"><img id="flecha"src="https://image.ibb.co/hR4xh9/flecha.png"></a>
   <h1 class="logo">MANUAIS E PROCESSOS<span id="fcor"> INFORMÁTICA<span><h1/>
  </header>
 <div id="interface">
  <article class="artigo">
   <h1 class="titulo">INSTALANDO SISTEMA OPERACIONAL</h1>
   <p class="paragrafo">
   <!--...<a class="link" href="F:\Campo Florido\Compartilhados\Informática\Comuns\planilha-modelo-formatacao.xlsx" download>Baixar o documento modelo de formatação em computadores</a><br>-->
   <span class="li">1.</span> Clique com o lado direito na bandeira do Windows ou use o atalho(Windows+X) para abrir o menu abaixo, nele escolha a opção "Sistema".<br><img src="https://image.ibb.co/fNqEUp/renomear1.jpg" class="icone"><br>
   <span class="li">2.</span> Vá em "Renomear este computador" e coloque o nome da etiqueta do computador, após isso será necessário reiniciar o computador.<br><img class="icone" src="https://image.ibb.co/jP7Hh9/renomear2.jpg"><br>
   </p>
  <article>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A dúvida que eu tinha não era referente a um código em si, e sim sobre css e html, se fosse colocar o código teria que colocar o de todas as páginas para ter uma comparação... Mas já resolvi e coloquei outra dúvida no lugar.

Comment: O problema é na logo ou na seta? Qual seria a logo? "Horizontalmente" ou "verticalmente"? Ficou bem confusa a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro dar uma lida [nesse guia](https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/) de `Flex Container`, onde terá diversos exemplos de centralização.

Abaixo está o código, utilizei o `justify-content: center` e o `align-items: center` para centralizar horizontalmente e verticalmente as `<div>` de cada elemento. Utilizei também o `flex-grow` para determinar o tamanho que cada um irá ocupar, deixando um pequeno espaço para a seta e todo o restante da área para o logo:

```js
$(document).scroll(function(){
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y < 25) {
    $('.cabecalho').css({'padding-top': '20px','padding-bottom': '20px'});
  }
  else {
    $('.cabecalho').css({'padding-top': '6px', 'padding-bottom': '6px'});
  }
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.postagem {
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,.05);
 margin: 0px;
}
.cabecalho {
 transition: 0.2s;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 height: 38px;
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 padding-top: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(255,140,40,1);
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
} 
.logo {
 color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 font-family: agency fb;
 font-size: 20pt;
}
#fcor {
 color: rgba(255,220,180,1);
}
.seta{
 flex-grow: 0;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 align-items: center;
}
.letras{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>teste</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="postagem">
  <header class="cabecalho">
    <a href="1009182.html">
      <div class="seta">
        <img src="https://image.ibb.co/hR4xh9/flecha.png">
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="letras">
      <h1 class="logo">MANUAIS E PROCESSOS<span id="fcor"> INFORMÁTICA </span></h1>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```